# Storing a function with jQuery data() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jQuery [.data() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) says the following:

> The `.data()` method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM element

I assume "any type" refers to functions as well. Say I have a div with the id foo as such:

```
<div id="foo">Foo!</div>
```

And I'd like to store a function in it called `say` that takes a parameter.
According to the documentation I'd store the function this way:

```
$("#foo").data("say", function(message){
   alert("Foo says "+message);
});
```

My question is, how do I invoke the function with a parameter when I wish to do so.

`$("#foo").data("say");` should return the function, but how would I pass a parameter to it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
var myFunction = $("#foo").data("say");
myFunction(someParameter);
```

Answer (score 43):

A better alternative to storing functions in `data` is using custom events. This can be done easily with [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$('#foo').on('say', function(e, arg){
    alert('Foo says ' + arg);
});

$('#foo').trigger('say', 'hello');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tW66j/

Note: on earlier versions of jQuery (until 1.7), [`.bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) was used instead of `.on`.

Comment: +1 - this is great advice, but Darin answered my question exactly.
Thank you very much.

Comment: sometimes it's useful. consider a case where you want an uniform way to fetch data that is semantically associated with the DOM node, but the implementation of the data-fetching varies depending on node type.

Comment: We could, of course, store an XPath or the target DOM node object itself to fetch but a callback function is more extensible and requires no duplication of DOM node objects

Comment: For anybody coming back to this several years later, 'bind' has been depreciated in favour of 'on'. $('#foo').on('say', function(e, arg){alert('Foo says ' + arg);});

Comment: @ATfPT - Good point, I updated the answer and the example. Thanks! By the way, the documentation doesn't say [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is deprecated (yet?). This is what deprecation looks like: [`die`](http://api.jquery.com/die/)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more elegant way to call the method.

```
// store the method with data
$('#foo').data('bar',function(){console.log("Givin it the business!")});

// Simple execution (this will not keep the method in scope)
$('#foo').data('bar')();

// scoped method execution with call([scope,arguments[]]), takes arguments with comma separation
$('#foo').data('bar').call($('#foo').first()[0],'arguemnts','for','method');

// scoped method execution with apply(scope[,argument[]]), takes an array of arguments
$('#foo').data('bar').apply($('#foo').first()[0],['arguemnts','for','method']);
```

Apply Method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Call Method:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Upvote for storing and calling functions using .data.
However, I tried this and when you call a function stored this way `$('#foo').data('bar')();` it looses its context. $(this) now refers to the DOMWindow, not $(#foo).

Kobi's solution however keeps the function's context for $(this).

Comment: yeah, that's not how to keep it in scope, you'll need to use the call or apply method to keep the execution in scope.

Comment: which jquery version is required for data() attribute