# jQuery Mobile Select Menu handler, trying to set a variable outside the scope of handler

Tags: jquery-mobile, closures, onchange, select-menu

I am trying to set a variable to the selected value of a select menu inside the select menus handler. The problem is that my variable isn't recognized within the context of the select handler and if I pass the select handler the variables context I can no longer access the value of the selected variable. Does any one know a work around?

```js
function object(){
    this.testVar;
    this.handler;
}

function makeObject(){
    var result = new object();
    result.testVar;
    result.handler = handler;
    return result;
}

function handler(){
   alert($(this).val());
   alert(this.testVar);
    //ultimately this is what I want to do
    this.testVar = $(this).val();
}

//If I do it this way $(this).val() is defined but not testVar
$("#test-select").on("change", {
        testdata: this.testVar
    }, this.handler);

//If I do it this way testVar is defined but not $(this).val()
$("#test-select").on("change", {
        testdata: this.testVar
    }, $.proxy(this.handler,this));
```

Comment: It kind of depends what you want to do with it, but it seems you could use jquery's .data() function to store testVar and handler "in" your DOM element (check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175257/storing-a-function-with-jquery-data-method for an exemple on how to use it with functions)

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide which context you want the handler to execute in, and pass the other context as a parameter to your handler function.

When the handler is called, 'this' will initially refer to the changed HTML element.  When you are setting up the listener, 'this' will refer to the object setting it up.

One example would be:

```js
function handler(obj) {
    alert($(this).val()); // this is the test-select object.
    alert(obj.testVar);
}

var self = this;
$("#test-select").on("change", {
    testdata: this.testVar
}, function() { self.handler(self); });
```